# Creating geodatabase, that has all layers used in creating map from different geodatabses?

Tags: arcmap, enterprise-geodatabase, file-geodatabase, esri-geodatabase

I have been working on creating a city map, that had layers sourced to different gdbs stored on my desktop, now my final product is ready after 3 months and I have to package the datasets and send only one Geodatabase that consists of all the layers used to create the exact city map. How can I do that without disrupting the original layout of the map?

[image]

Pictures for reference. (Sorry, but my boss wouldn't let me reveal the gdb names)

Comment: This sounds like the use case for a Map Package.

Comment: I can't use Map package, the client says it's non compliant.

Comment: I would ask the client why they are assessing it to be non-compliant. If your question accurately reflects their requirements then they may not be fully understanding Map Package functionality.